# I got server error when using Bitnami Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bitnami

I manage 3 websites on one server instance. I set the Bitnami.conf like below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName morethanair.com
  ServerAlias morethanair.com
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName microblog.morethanair.com
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/microblog-wordpress/"
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/microblog-wordpress/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName photo.morethanair.com
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/photo-wordpress/"
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/photo-wordpress/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
# Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

I can connect 2 sites with subdomain (photo.morethanair.com and microblog.morethanair.com), but the server error occurred when I try to connect morethanair.com.
When I type 'morethanair.com' in the browser, the URL changes to 'morethanair.com//' with double slash.

Any idea to resolve this?

I already tried to delete Wordpress and all plug-ins and reinstalled the latest Wordpress, but it didn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you migrate your question to [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: @AdisonMasih, Thank you for your suggestion, I got to know a useful site.